# Como implementar o lock pessimista em Java WEB EJB?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com problemas de concorrência em meu sistema, preciso inserir o *lock* pessimista porque os usuários acessam e salvam ao mesmo tempo, causando erros bizarros no resultado.

Comment: não sei de java e hibernate, mas concorrencia pra salvar dados, ou você está fazendo algo errado no código (hora do insert/ update) ou resolve com isolamento de transações

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [método `lock(Object, LockModeType)` do `EntityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-). A forma de uso é essa:

```
AlgumaEntidade x = ...;
EntityManager em = ...;
em.lock(x, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Para trazer uma entidade do banco de dados já com o *lock* pessimista, use o [método `find` que tem um `LockModeType` como parâmetro](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-):

```
EntityManager em = ...;
AlgumaEntidade x = em.find(AlgumaEntidade.class, pk, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

O método `refresh`, que atualiza o estado da entidade ao reler ela da base de dados, também tem uma sobrecarga com `LockModeType`:

```
AlgumaEntidade x = ...;
em.refresh(x, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Os objetos `Query` (e por consequência, `TypedQuery` e `StoredProcedureQuery`) também tem suporte ao lock pessimista por meio do [método `setLockMode(LockModeType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setLockMode-javax.persistence.LockModeType-):

```
String jpql = ...;
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

Tal como os demais métodos de `Query`, ele pode ser encadeado:

```
String jpql = ...;
AlgumaEntidade x = em.createQuery(jpql, AlgumaEntidade.class)
        .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
        .setParameter(1, "blabla")
        .getSingleResult();
```

A anotação `NamedQuery` também tem um [campo `lockMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html#lockMode--) opcional.

O `EntityManager` também tem um [método `getLockMode(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getLockMode-java.lang.Object-) que pode ser usado para se descobrir qual é o tipo de *lock* que está sendo aplicado a alguma entidade. O `Query` também tem um [método `getLockMode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getLockMode--) que obtém o `LockModeType` que se aplica à `Query`.

O [enum `LockModeType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) tem os seguintes elementos: `NONE`, `OPTIMISTIC`, `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`, `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`, `PESSIMISTIC_READ`, `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, `READ` e `WRITE`.

O `READ` é um sinônimo para `OPTIMISTIC` e o `WRITE` é um sinônimo para `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`. Eles existem por motivos históricos e na minha opinião deveriam ser marcados como `@Deprecated`. O motivo histórico no caso é porque eles são legados do JPA 1, que [só tinha os modos `READ` e `WRITE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html). A partir do JPA 2, a parte de *locking* foi revista e reformulada, e os demais modos foram criados, tornando esses dois modos já existentes obsoletos.

O modo `NONE` é o que desativa qualquer *locking* e deixa acontecer qualquer coisa que aconteça. Esse é o modo padrão para entidades que não contém algum campo anotado com `@Version`.

O modo `OPTIMISTIC` é o que usa o *lock* otimista, mas isso só funciona quando há um campo `@Version`. Caso contrário, se comporta que nem o `NONE`. Quando aplicado em entidades versionadas, permite que essa possa ser lida por outras threads, mas não alterada ou excluída. Caso sofra alterações ou exclusões concorrentes, um `OptimisticLockException` é lançado.

O modo `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` é semelhante ao `OPTIMISTIC`, mas ele força o incremento da versão. Como consequência, ela faz com que a entidade seja modificada, de forma que se houver duas threads acessando a mesma entidade dessa forma, a última que for fazer o *commit* vai ter um `OptimisticLockException`.

Os modos otimistas não utilizam o mecanismo de *lock* do SGBD e ao invés disso, fazem o *lock* na aplicação. Já os modos pessimistas delegam o *lock* ao SGBD.

O modo `PESSIMISTIC_READ` bloqueia as tuplas no banco de dados para alteração e exclusão, mas ainda permitem leituras concorrentes.

O modo `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` bloqueia as tuplas no banco de dados para alteração, exclusão e leituras concorrentes.

O modo `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` é a combinação do `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` com o `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`. Serve para quando você quer usar o *lock* otimista e pessimista ao mesmo tempo ou para quando você faz *lock* pessimista em entidades versionadas que devam sofrer alteração.

Se um *lock* pessimista não puder ser obtido do banco de dados, uma `PessimisticLockException` é lançada.

Se o *provider* JPA precisar ou quiser, ele pode promover um *lock* `OPTIMISTIC` para `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` ou um `PESSIMISTIC_READ` para `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`. Em especial, ele fará isso se a entidade em questão sofrer alteração ou exclusão. É possível obter `OptimisticLockException` ou `PessimisticLockException` se essa promoção não for possível.

O Hibernate também conta com dois modos de *lock* otimista que não são padrão do JPA que é o `ALL`, que verifica se qualquer campo da entidade sofreu alguma alteração concorrente e o `DIRTY` que verifica se algum dos campos modificados da entidade sofreu alguma alteração concorrente, mas permite que alterações concorrentes alterem os demais campos.

O modo pessimista tem um *timeout* que pode ser especificado com a propriedade `javax.persistence.lock.timeout`. Ele pode ser especificado nos métodos do `EntityManager` que recem uma lista de propriedades junto com o `LockModeType`. Esses métodos são, a saber: [`lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-java.util.Map-); [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-java.util.Map-) e [`refresh`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-java.util.Map-). O método [`setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) também pode ser usado. Ele também pode ser especificado no `persistence.xml`, na anotação `@NamedQuery` ou então ao criar-se o `EntityManagerFactory`. Quando essa propriedade tem o valor 0, significa que tentar-se-á adquirir o *lock* pessimista imediatamente e caso isso não seja possível, uma `LockTimeoutException` é imediatamente lançada. Caso o valor seja diferente, o *provider* JPA espera para tentar adquirir o *lock* novamente antes de lançar uma `LockTimeoutException`. Esse valor está em milissegundos. No entanto essa propriedade é apenas um *hint*, portanto o *provider* JPA pode escolher por desobedecê-la se assim preferir.

Mais informações:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjhz.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507470/540552
- https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic-lock-mode-work/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-pessimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/
- https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/locking-and-concurrency-in-java-persistence-20
- https://www.intertech.com/Blog/hibernate-optimistic-lock-without-a-version-or-timestamp/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/an-entity-modeling-strategy-for-scaling-optimistic-locking/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-prevent-optimisticlockexception-using-hibernate-versionless-optimistic-locking/
- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf (seção 3.4)